# Error code E000716 on Canon Photo Copier iR2022i

Tags: hardware-failure

The error immediately appear when I open that photo copier iR2022i and I cannot do anything else. Please see the below about error message.

> > Turn the main power switch (on the main unit's right side) OFF and ON again.
> >
> > If the machine still does not operate normally, contact your service representative with the error code below.
> >
> > E 000716

Answer (score 1):

From the [Canon iR2030 series Service Manual](http://www.scribd.com/doc/57353174/Canon-Ir2030-series-Service-Manual) (which includes the iR2022i), error 716 is
"Erroneous communication with optional cassette".

I suggest you pull it out, clean off any electrical contacts you can spot, and shove it back in.